# Find scalars of vectors that equals to zero

Tags: linear-algebra

$x\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0\\-3\\1\end{bmatrix}$ +
$y\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-5\\2\\-4\end{bmatrix}$ +
$z\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-20\\-1\\-13\end{bmatrix}$
=$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

x = ？ y = ? z = ?

RREF = $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&3\\0&1&4\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

I started with looking for the Reduced Row Echelon Form, but don't know what to do next.

Comment: Do you miss the plus signs? And what methods have you known?

Comment: Hi Jack, I tried to make in into RREF, but am I right to start with that?

Comment: This gives you a system of three linear equations in three unknowns, which can be solved in the standard manner. Have you attempted this, or are you confused in how to set up the problem?

Comment: Since i know these 3 set of vectors are linear dependent, so i'm trying to figure out the scalars.

Comment: Do you have difficulties in finding the RREF? Or you have found the RREF but don't know how to go on?

Comment: I've found the RREF, but don't know what to do next

Comment: Good. Then you should add that into your post. I assume that you may have seen an example showing how to read solutions (if any) for the RREF.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about $x=y=z=0?$

Comment: Hi, since 3 of them are linear dependent, so 0 is not the only solution of x,y,z.
I am trying to find solution that is not 0

Comment: I don't find the same last row in the RREF.

Comment: You got the RREF wrong. One would get the $3\times 3$ identity matrix if one does the calculation correctly and thus $x=y=z=0$ is the unique solution.

You can use this [online tool][1] to see all the intermediate steps.


  [1]: http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?c=roc

Comment: Hi guys.. My bad, the second number in the second vector should be 2 instead of -2.. Then the RREF should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\cdot\begin{bmatrix}0\\-3\\1\end{bmatrix}$ +
$y\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-5\\2\\-4\end{bmatrix}$ +
$z\cdot\begin{bmatrix}-20\\-1\\-13\end{bmatrix}$
=$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$\implies \begin{bmatrix}-5y-20z\\-3x+2y-z\\x-4y-13z\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

$\implies y=-4z, -3x-9z=0, x+3z=0$

$\implies y=-4z, x=-3z$

$\implies\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=c\begin{bmatrix}-3\\-4\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Supposin your RREF is exact (which it is *not*), there remains to interpret it as an equivalent linear system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
x+3z=0\\y+4z=0
\end{cases}\implies \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-3z\\-4z\\\quad z\end{bmatrix}=z\begin{bmatrix}-3\\-4\\\quad1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix is full rank which can be verified with numerical maths software (such as MATLAB).

That means your vectors are in fact **linearly independent**.

Therefore, only the trivial solution exists:
$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix} = \bf{0}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  OP edited and changed the matrix